# Docker config : Celery + RabbitMQ

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, celery, docker-compose, dockerfile

How do I run Celery and RabbitMQ in a docker container? Can you point me to sample dockerfile or compose files?

This is what I have:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.4
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /tasker
ADD requirements.txt /tasker/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /tasker/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
rabbitmq:
  image: tutum/rabbitmq
  environment:
    - RABBITMQ_PASS=mypass
  ports:
    - "5672:5672"   
    - "15672:15672"
celery:
  build: .
  command: celery worker --app=tasker.tasks
  volumes:
    - .:/tasker
  links:
    - rabbitmq:rabbit
```

The issue I'm having is I cant get Celery to stay alive or running. It keeps exiting.

Comment: Can't you use the docker images of celery? I am not sure what you are trying to do with your Dockerfile either. One thing for suer is, it is missing ENTRYPOINT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2018, as [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870763/docker-config-celery-rabbitmq/37875717#comment85463597_37875717) by [Floran Gmehlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874054/floran-gmehlin), The celery image is now officially deprecated in favor of the [official python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).

As commented in [celery/issue 1](https://github.com/docker-library/celery/issues/1#issuecomment-287655769):

> Using this image seems ridiculous. If you have an application container, as you usually have with Django, you need all dependencies (things you import in `tasks.py`) installed in this container again.
>
> That's why other projects (e.g. cookiecutter-django) [reuse the application container](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/bd645cbac5d989967d9d66270a60239a91a0c21a/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/docker-compose.yml#L33-L57) for Celery, and only run a different command (command: `celery ... worker`) against it with `docker-compose`.

Note, now the `docker-compose.yml` is called [`local.yml`](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/local.yml#L51-L75) and use [`start.sh`](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/local/django/celery/worker/start.sh).

---

Original answer:

You can try and emulate the official [celery Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/celery/blob/0652407560f353e749cbe001e8bdbb5db86c2291/Dockerfile), which does a bit more setup before the `CMD ["celery", "worker"]`.

See [the usage of that image](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/celery#how-to-use-this-image) to run it properly.

> start a celery worker (RabbitMQ Broker)

```
$ docker run --link some-rabbit:rabbit --name some-celery -d celery
```

> check the status of the cluster

```
$ docker run --link some-rabbit:rabbit --rm celery celery status
```

If you can use that image in your docker-compose, then you can try building your own starting `FROM celery` instead of `FROM python`.

Comment: The celery image is now officially deprecated in favor of the official python image : https://hub.docker.com/r/library/celery/

Comment: @FloranGmehlin Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

I have similar Celery exiting problem while dockerizing the application. You should use rabbit service name ( in your case it's `rabbitmq`) as host name in your celery configuration.That is, 
use `broker_url = 'amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672//'` instead of `broker_url = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'` . 
In my case, major components are  Flask, Celery and Redis.My problem is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242894/couldnt-start-celery-with-docker-compose) please check the link, you may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

something I used in my docker-compose.yml. it works for me. check the details in this [medium](https://medium.com/@tonywangcn/how-to-build-docker-cluster-with-celery-and-rabbitmq-in-10-minutes-13fc74d21730#.1m9wt25e2)

```
version: '2'
services:
rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
    ports:
        - "5672:5672"

worker:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: dockerfile
    volumes:
        - .:/app
    links:
        - rabbit
    depends_on:
        - rabbit
```