# couldn't start Celery with docker-compose

Tags: docker, flask, celery, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have Flask app with Celery worker and Redis and it's working normally as expected when running on local machine. Then I tried to Dockerize the application. When I trying to build/start the services ( ie, flask app, Celery, and Redis) using `sudo docker-compose up` all services are running except Celery and showing an error as

> ImportError: No module named 'my_celery'

But, the same code working in local machine without any errors. Can any one suggest the solution?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.5-slim
WORKDIR celery_sample
ADD . /celery_sample
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: "python my_celery.py"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - webnet
    volumes:
      - .:/celery_sample

  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
      - webnet


  celery:
    image: celery:3.1.25
    command: "celery worker -A my_celery -l INFO"
    volumes:
      - .:/celery_sample
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

**requirements.txt**

```
flask==0.10
redis
requests==2.11.1
celery==3.1.25
```

**my_celery.py** ( kindly ignore the logic)

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
celery_app = Celery('my_celery')
celery_app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')



@celery_app.task
def add_celery():
    return str(int(10)+int(40))


@flask_app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Index Page"

@flask_app.route('/add')
def add_api():
    add_celery.delay()
    return "Added to Queue"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.debug = True
    flask_app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**celeryconfig.py**

```
## Broker settings.
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'    
## Using the database to store task state and results.
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all the celery image is deprecated in favour of standard python image more info [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/celery/).

`WORKDIR` sets the working directory for all the command after it is defined in the Dockerfile, which means the command which you are try to run will run from that directory. Docker image for celery sets the working directory to `/home/user`.

Since your code is mounted on `/celery_smaple` and the working directory is `/home/user`, Celery is not able to find your python module.

One alternative is to cd into the mounted directory and execute the command:

```
celery:
    image: celery:3.1.25
    command: "cd /celery_sample && celery worker -A my_celery -l INFO"
    volumes:
      - .:/celery_sample
    networks:
      - webnet
```

notice the command

And another one is to create your own image with `WORKDIR` set to `/celery_sample` eg:

```
FROM python:3.5
RUN pip install celery==3.1.25
WORKDIR /celery_sample
```

after building you own image you can use the compose file by changing the `image` of celery service

**Edit**

You need to link the services to one another in order to communicate:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: "python my_celery.py"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - webnet
    volumes:
      - .:/celery_sample
    links:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
      - webnet

  celery:
    image: celery:3.1.25
    command: "celery worker -A my_celery -l INFO"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/user
    networks:
      - webnet
    links:
      - redis

networks:
  webnet:
```

and your configuration file should be:

```
## Broker settings.
BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'    
## Using the database to store task state and results.
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
```

once you have linked the services in compose file you can access the service by using the service name as the hostname.

Comment: I made some changes to my project after reading your answer. **1:** Mounted the project contents to celery services'  **WORKDIR** as `volumes:
      - .:/home/user`  and remains `command` unchanged **2:** I build  **celery service**  with another Dockerfile and inside that Dockerfile I installed same **requirements.txt** . ( this done because I couldn't run celery worker without the dependencies) . **3:** EXPOSEd the port 6379 in both Dockerfiles.

Comment: Now problem is celery couldn't find redis server. The error is `celery_1  | [2017-07-22 03:44:52,778: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379/0: .
celery_1  | Trying again in 12.00 seconds...`  @vedarthk @Tarun Lalwani

Comment: It's Worked. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

The simplest change you can make is to map the directory for celery image correctly in yaml

```
  celery:
    image: celery:3.1.25
    command: "celery worker -A my_celery -l INFO"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/user/
    networks:
      - webnet
```

Also as @vedarthk pointed, you should be using the official Python image for this instead of celery image